# Translate validation message in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem translating the laravel messages. I have created a folder called `es` inside `lang` folder and I have translated the messages from English to Spanish. Also I have set `'locale' => 'es'` on `config/app.php`. But English messages continues appearing.

I have used the default views for login provided by laravel, to generate it (and routes) I used the command (as says in https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication)

`php artisan make:auth`

I have changed the default routes by the following:

```
Route::get('/login', 'UserController@getLogin');
Route::post('/login', 'UserController@postLogin');
```

And in UserController I have:

```
public function getLogin(){
    return view('auth.login');
}

public function postLogin(Request $request){
    $input = $request->all();
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $input["email"], 'password' => $input["password"]], true))
    {
        return redirect()->intended('/tables');
    }
}
```

Here are two screenshots of the messages that appears in English

http://i64.tinypic.com/if4k83.png

http://i64.tinypic.com/51zhnp.png

How can I transate these messages?

Thanks

Edit:

`resources/lang/en/validation.php`

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Validation Language Lines
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The following language lines contain the default error messages used by
    | the validator class. Some of these rules have multiple versions such
    | as the size rules. Feel free to tweak each of these messages here.
    |
    */

    'accepted'             => 'The :attribute must be accepted.',
    'active_url'           => 'The :attribute is not a valid URL.',
    'after'                => 'The :attribute must be a date after :date.',
    'alpha'                => 'The :attribute may only contain letters.',
    'alpha_dash'           => 'The :attribute may only contain letters, numbers, and dashes.',
    'alpha_num'            => 'The :attribute may only contain letters and numbers.',
    'array'                => 'The :attribute must be an array.',
    'before'               => 'The :attribute must be a date before :date.',
    'between'              => [
        'numeric' => 'The :attribute must be between :min and :max.',
        'file'    => 'The :attribute must be between :min and :max kilobytes.',
        'string'  => 'The :attribute must be between :min and :max characters.',
        'array'   => 'The :attribute must have between :min and :max items.',
    ],
    'boolean'              => 'The :attribute field must be true or false.',
    'confirmed'            => 'The :attribute confirmation does not match.',
    'date'                 => 'The :attribute is not a valid date.',
    'date_format'          => 'The :attribute does not match the format :format.',
    'different'            => 'The :attribute and :other must be different.',
    'digits'               => 'The :attribute must be :digits digits.',
    'digits_between'       => 'The :attribute must be between :min and :max digits.',
    'distinct'             => 'The :attribute field has a duplicate value.',
    'email'                => 'The :attribute must be a valid email address.',
    'exists'               => 'The selected :attribute is invalid.',
    'filled'               => 'The :attribute field is required.',
    'image'                => 'The :attribute must be an image.',
    'in'                   => 'The selected :attribute is invalid.',
    'in_array'             => 'The :attribute field does not exist in :other.',
    'integer'              => 'The :attribute must be an integer.',
    'ip'                   => 'The :attribute must be a valid IP address.',
    'json'                 => 'The :attribute must be a valid JSON string.',
    'max'                  => [
        'numeric' => 'The :attribute may not be greater than :max.',
        'file'    => 'The :attribute may not be greater than :max kilobytes.',
        'string'  => 'The :attribute may not be greater than :max characters.',
        'array'   => 'The :attribute may not have more than :max items.',
    ],
    'mimes'                => 'The :attribute must be a file of type: :values.',
    'min'                  => [
        'numeric' => 'The :attribute must be at least :min.',
        'file'    => 'The :attribute must be at least :min kilobytes.',
        'string'  => 'The :attribute must be at least :min characters.',
        'array'   => 'The :attribute must have at least :min items.',
    ],
    'not_in'               => 'The selected :attribute is invalid.',
    'numeric'              => 'The :attribute must be a number.',
    'present'              => 'The :attribute field must be present.',
    'regex'                => 'The :attribute format is invalid.',
    'required'             => 'The :attribute field is required.',
    'required_if'          => 'The :attribute field is required when :other is :value.',
    'required_unless'      => 'The :attribute field is required unless :other is in :values.',
    'required_with'        => 'The :attribute field is required when :values is present.',
    'required_with_all'    => 'The :attribute field is required when :values is present.',
    'required_without'     => 'The :attribute field is required when :values is not present.',
    'required_without_all' => 'The :attribute field is required when none of :values are present.',
    'same'                 => 'The :attribute and :other must match.',
    'size'                 => [
        'numeric' => 'The :attribute must be :size.',
        'file'    => 'The :attribute must be :size kilobytes.',
        'string'  => 'The :attribute must be :size characters.',
        'array'   => 'The :attribute must contain :size items.',
    ],
    'string'               => 'The :attribute must be a string.',
    'timezone'             => 'The :attribute must be a valid zone.',
    'unique'               => 'The :attribute has already been taken.',
    'url'                  => 'The :attribute format is invalid.',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Custom Validation Language Lines
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify custom validation messages for attributes using the
    | convention "attribute.rule" to name the lines. This makes it quick to
    | specify a specific custom language line for a given attribute rule.
    |
    */

    'custom' => [
        'attribute-name' => [
            'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Custom Validation Attributes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The following language lines are used to swap attribute place-holders
    | with something more reader friendly such as E-Mail Address instead
    | of "email". This simply helps us make messages a little cleaner.
    |
    */

    'attributes' => [],

];
```

`resources/lang/es/validation.php`

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Validation Language Lines
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The following language lines contain the default error messages used by
    | the validator class. Some of these rules have multiple versions such
    | as the size rules. Feel free to tweak each of these messages here.
    |
    */

    'accepted'             => ':attribute debe ser aceptado.',
    'active_url'           => 'El campo :attribute no es una URL válida.',
    'after'                => 'El campo :attribute debe ser una fecha posterior a :date.',
    'alpha'                => 'El campo :attribute debe contener solo letras.',
    'alpha_dash'           => 'El campo :attribute debe contener solo letras números y guiones.',
    'alpha_num'            => 'El campo :attribute debe contenterdebe contenter letras y números.',
    'array'                => 'El campo :attribute debe ser un array.',
    'before'               => 'El campo :attribute debe ser una fecha anterior a :date.',
    'between'              => [
        'numeric' => 'El campo :attribute debe estar entre :min y :max.',
        'file'    => 'El campo :attribute ebe estar entre :min y :max kilobytes.',
        'string'  => 'El campo :attribute ebe estar entre :min y :max carácteres.',
        'array'   => 'El campo :attribute debe tener entre :min y :max elementos.',
    ],
    'boolean'              => 'El campo :attribute debe ser verdadero o falso.',
    'confirmed'            => 'El campo :attribute confirmación no coincide.',
    'date'                 => 'El campo :attribute no es una fecha válida.',
    'date_format'          => 'El campo :attribute does not match the format :format.',
    'different'            => 'El campo :attribute y :other deben ser diferentes.',
    'digits'               => 'El campo :attribute debe ser de :digits dígitos.',
    'digits_between'       => 'El campo :attribute debe estar entre :min y :max dígitos.',
    'distinct'             => 'El campo :attribute tiene un valor duplicado.',
    'email'                => 'El campo :attribute debe ser una dirección de correo válida.',
    'exists'               => 'El campo :attribute no es válido.',
    'filled'               => 'El campo :attribute es obligatorio.',
    'image'                => 'El campo :attribute debe ser una imagen.',
    'in'                   => 'El campo :attribute no es válido',
    'in_array'             => 'El campo :attribute no existe en :other.',
    'integer'              => 'El campo :attribute debe ser un entero.',
    'ip'                   => 'El campo :attribute debe ser una dirección IP válida.',
    'json'                 => 'El campo :attribute debe ser una cadena JSON válida.',
    'max'                  => [
        'numeric' => 'El campo :attribute no debe ser mayor que :max.',
        'file'    => 'El campo :attribute no debe ser mayor que :max kilobytes.',
        'string'  => 'El campo :attribute no debe ser mayor que :max carácteres.',
        'array'   => 'El campo :attribute no debe contener más de :max elementos.',
    ],
    'mimes'                => 'El campo :attribute debe ser un archivo del tipo: :values.',
    'min'                  => [
        'numeric' => 'El campo :attribute debe ser de al menos :min.',
        'file'    => 'El campo :attribute debe ser de al menos :min kilobytes.',
        'string'  => 'El campo :attribute debe ser de al menos :min carácteres.',
        'array'   => 'El campo :attribute debe tener al menos :min elementos.',
    ],
    'not_in'               => 'El campo selected :attribute no es válido.',
    'numeric'              => 'El campo :attribute debe ser un número.',
    'present'              => 'El campo :attribute debe estar presente.',
    'regex'                => 'El formatp del campo :attribute no es válido.',
    'required'             => 'El campo :attribute es obligatorio.',
    'required_if'          => 'El campo :attribute es obligatorio cuando :other es :value.',
    'required_unless'      => 'El campo :attribute es obligatorio a menos que :other esté en :values.',
    'required_with'        => 'El campo :attribute es obligatorio cuando :values está presente.',
    'required_with_all'    => 'El campo :attribute es obligatorio cuando :values está presente.',
    'required_without'     => 'El campo :attribute es obligatorio cuando :values no está presente.',
    'required_without_all' => 'El campo :attribute es obligatorio cuando ninguno de :values está presente.',
    'same'                 => 'Los campos :attribute y :other deben coincidir.',
    'size'                 => [
        'numeric' => 'El campo :attribute debe ser de :size.',
        'file'    => 'El campo :attribute debe ser de :size kilobytes.',
        'string'  => 'El campo :attribute debe ser de :size carácteres.',
        'array'   => 'El campo :attribute debe contenter :size elementos.',
    ],
    'string'               => 'El campo :attribute debe ser una cadena de texto.',
    'timezone'             => 'El campo :attribute debe ser una zona válida.',
    'unique'               => 'El campo :attribute debe ser único.',
    'url'                  => 'El campo :attribute tiene un formato no válido.',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Custom Validation Language Lines
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify custom validation messages for attributes using the
    | convention "attribute.rule" to name the lines. This makes it quick to
    | specify a specific custom language line for a given attribute rule.
    |
    */

    'custom' => [
        'attribute-name' => [
            'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Custom Validation Attributes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The following language lines are used to swap attribute place-holders
    | with something more reader friendly such as E-Mail Address instead
    | of "email". This simply helps us make messages a little cleaner.
    |
    */

    'attributes' => [],

];
```

The begining of my `config/app.php`

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Environment
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
    | running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
    | services your application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
    |
    */

    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'es',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'es',
```

Comment: Could you add the content of both translation files?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code of both files.

Comment: Did you clear the cache? ``Php artisan cache:clear`` and what happends when u change the fallback_locale to es?

Comment: I execute now `php artisan cache:clear` and set es as fallback:_locale and nothing happens

Comment: try `dd(App::isLocale('es'))` is laravel using the correct locale when routes are called?

Comment: The output is `false`. I update my question with the begining of my `config/app.php`

Comment: Hmm and what happends when you do App::setLocale('es'); in your controller

Comment: If I set `App::setLocale('es')` at the begining of routes.php the message that say that the email is not in the data base is translate: http://i67.tinypic.com/o6egwy.png But the other message doesn't change: http://i66.tinypic.com/2cnf69f.png . The default views in laravel uses bootstrap. It is possible that the last message (the message that is in English) was part of bootstrap?

Answer (score 5):

1. Define your language in .env (you can always check what language you are running on with `app()->getLocale()`)
2. Copy `resource/lang/validation.php` to `resources/lang/{YOUR_LANG}/validation.php`
3. Find and edit this array:

> ```
> /*
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Custom Validation Language Lines
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |
> | Here you may specify custom validation messages for attributes using the
> | convention "attribute.rule" to name the lines. This makes it quick to
> | specify a specific custom language line for a given attribute rule.
> |
> */
>
> 'custom' => [
>     'attribute-name' => [
>         'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
>     ],
> ],
> ```

Example:

```
'custom' => [
    'mensagem' => [
        'required' => 'O campo mensagem é obrigatório.',
    ],
],
```